# How to port C/C++ code onto iOS?

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS, and would like to seek tips of porting a C/C++ code, previous written for Linux.

Only a few things particular about the code.

1. pthread
2. socket
3. non-blocking I/O with select()
4. daemon

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX threads and sockets are also available for use on iOS. If you want to make a daemon, you have to jailbreak your device to install it.